# Disable form submit on multiple ui-select for Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, ui-select, angularjs-select2

When using the multiple version of [UI-Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) for AngularJS the form is submitted once a user presses enter. Many users start typing a tag and press enter to select it and search for a new one. But once the users presses enter the form is submitted.

What is the best 'Angular' way to disabled this?

See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/00aBNnSmDvoqUnDuW0vr)

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2"  style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors}}</p>

  <div style="height:500px"></div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, this [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/5T8dIn6CC2GPZbHZ1oF5?p=preview) will work for you. Please leave your comment if you want to achieve something else.

**index.html**

```
<ui-select ng-keypress="selec2_keypress($event)" multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2"  style="width: 300px;">
```

**demo.js**

```
 $scope.selec2_keypress = function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13)
      event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply avoid from the `ng-submit` and use `ng-click` on a button to submit the form,

```
<form>
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2"  style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors}}</p>

  <div style="height:500px"></div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

don't forget to define the `button` type to `button`, if there is no type for a button in a form it is a `submit` button of the form by default.

Comment: My forms actually only has 1 required field. By disabling ng-submit on the form I'm blocking out my power users that enter the required field and press enter because they don't need fill anything else in.
It's a solution but not the perfect solution in my eyes